# Any recommendations for this type of UI in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a view on iOS with a bunch of UI widgets like sliders and buttons. Imagine that one of the controls changes a few of the buttons displayed to be a different set of buttons. What is the best way to handle this? Is it possible to duplicate my current view, change some of the buttons around and then point to the new one when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create all of the controls you want and keep references to them. Then set view.hidden = YES on the ones you want to hide and view.hidden = NO on the ones you want to show.

Comment: Maybe my question is that I also like the ability to manipulate the new set of buttons using Interface Builder because they will have a slightly different layout. Its a lot easier to set the position, size, etc visually. I guess a solution would be to lay them out in IB, write down the coordinates and then use those coordinates in code?

Comment: That's one way to do it. Another way would be to create a plain UIView in Interface Builder and then put a group of buttons into it. You can then hide or unhide all of the buttons in that group by setting the single UIView.hidden property.